# Xcode 4 Assertion Error

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4

I am getting an assertion error when I launch Xcode 4, which I just installed.  I have looked on Google and Stackoverflow, and I could not find anybody with the same problem as me.  As soon as I open Xcode 4, it shows me the welcome screen.  I try to open a project, and Xcode gives me a message saying I can continue using Xcode in an inconsistent state or I can crash Xcode.  When I click on more details it says "ASSERTION ERROR" followed by some other debugging info.  I can't copy it because when I try to highlight it Xcode freezes completely.

Any suggestions?

NOTE: This is different from other people who get this error when they build, I am getting this when it is LAUNCHED.

Could it also be because I am continuing a project from the previous version of Xcode?

[UPDATE] I have solved the problem. If you are also encountering such an error, try reinstalling Xcode 4.  If you continue getting the same error, then follow the advice of @mrueg.

Comment: I tried to reinstall Xcode, and it worked fine.

Comment: not working for me..dunno y..but in my case it has to deal with loading the xib file for iphone development..It just crashes xcode with ASSERTION ERROR saying interface builder cant lod or somefin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 4 has various bugs, and the assertion error is just a general warning that an inconsistency was detected.
The best way to get more info on the actual error that happened is to crash Xcode when you get the error and *then* show the details.

It probably also makes sense to send the crash report to Apple so they can fix the bug.

It is probably best to keep using Xcode 3 (which is still downloadable for the newest SDKs) and wait for the next version of Xcode 4 if your project crashes it.

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work!  Still don't know what was wrong, but I reinstalled it and it worked :)  Thanks anyway for the help!